# First Java Swing Project. Am i on the right track or totally in the wrong direction?

Tags: java, swing

Hey Guys i got this project and i have a few questions about it..

**Here is the Task:**

You are requested to create a GUI based application which will allow users to manage fleets of boats. The application is for a fleet management company who manage fleets of boats on behalf of different customers.

A fleet is composed of multiple boats. Initially there are no fleets or boats, but the application will allow the user to add a fleet. They will then be able to add boats to a fleet. There are two types of boats: Passenger and Freight. Each fleet has a fleet identification number, the name of the company that owns the fleet e.g. Irish Ferries, and zero or more boats.
Each boat will have a name e.g. Ulysses, and number of staff. In addition, each passenger boat will have a passenger capacity (no of passengers it can carry), and whether or not it can carry cars. Each freight boat will have a container capacity.

You should create a Boat super class which has two subclasses of PassengerBoat and FreightBoat. There should be one overall FleetManagementCompany class which can have a name e.g. FLeet Mgmt Ltd., contains at most 5 Fleets (Fleet class). The Fleet class will contain zero or more boats.

**Part A**

**1.**  The GUI based application should allow the user to create a fleet management company record. Theoretically it would allow you to create multiple fleet management company records.

**2.**  It should allow the user to add/remove fleets from the fleet management company.

**3.**  It should allow the user to add/remove boats from fleets.

**Part B**

The fleet management company also manages the sailing schedules for the fleets. There should be a fixed set of sailing routes and a fixed set of sailing times and durations.

**1.**  The application should allow the user to schedule sailings for each boat from a fleet

**2.**  You are free to devise your own implementation of the scheduling functionality.

**And Here is what i did so far:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Boat extends JFrame 
{



/// JTextField text = new JTextField(""  ,50);
    private static String labelPrefixs = "Fleets made: ";
    private static String labelPrefixww = "Boats usbed: ";
    private static String labelPrefix = "Number of  boats added: ";

    private int numClicks = 0;
    private int numAmy = 0;
    JLabel adbf = new JLabel(labelPrefixww + "0    ");
    JLabel addb = new JLabel(labelPrefix + "0    "); 
    JLabel amys = new JLabel(labelPrefixs + "0    "); 


    public Boat(String title) 
    {
        super(title);

        // operation to do when the window is closed.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        setBounds(500, 500, 800, 400);
        JButton back = new JButton("Back to start!");
        JButton button = new JButton("Click here to see Fleets!");
        JButton book = new JButton("Add Boat!");
        JButton del = new JButton("Delete Boat!");
        JButton route = new JButton("Get routes!");
        final JLabel choss = new JLabel("Choose sea-line");
        final JLabel chost = new JLabel("Choose Type of boat");
        final JLabel chosb = new JLabel("Choose a boat");
         final JButton fer = new JButton("Irish ferries");
         final JButton ferr = new JButton("British ferries");
         final JButton pass = new JButton("Passanger");
         final JButton freig = new JButton("Freight");
         final JButton ifer = new JButton("Frank");
         final JButton iferr = new JButton("Amy");
         final JButton iferrr = new JButton("Jackson");
         final JButton addf = new JButton("Make a Fleet");


        addf.setFocusPainted(false);
        pass.setFocusPainted(false);
        freig.setFocusPainted(false);
        route.setFocusPainted(false);
        fer.setFocusPainted(false);
        ferr.setFocusPainted(false);
        ifer.setFocusPainted(false);
        iferr.setFocusPainted(false);
        iferrr.setFocusPainted(false);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        back.setFocusPainted(false);
        book.setFocusPainted(false);
        del.setFocusPainted(false);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        button.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);


        JLabel ship1 = new JLabel( "<html><p>Owned By: Irish Fleets. <br></br> " + 
                                    "Class : B. <br></br>  " +
                                    "Passanger compacity: 300. <br></br>  " +
                                    "Seats available: 62. <br></br>     "+
                                    "Destination: Wonderland. <br></br> "+
                                    "Transport space: 5 cars. <br></br> "+" </p></html>");
        TitledBorder titled = new TitledBorder("Amy");
        ship1.setBorder(titled);
        add(ship1);

        JLabel ship2 = new JLabel( "<html><p>Owned By: Irish Fleets. <br></br> " + 
                                    "Class : A. <br></br>  " +
                                    "Passanger compacity: 200. <br></br>  " +
                                    "Seats available: 26. <br></br>     "+
                                    "Destination: Wonderland. <br></br> "+
                                    "Transport space: 15 cars. <br></br>    "+" </p></html>");
        TitledBorder titled1 = new TitledBorder("Frank");
        ship2.setBorder(titled1);
        add(ship2);

        panel.add(chost);
        panel.add(freig);
        panel.add(pass);
        panel.add(book);
        panel.add(del);
        panel.add(ship1);
        panel.add(ship2);
        panel.add(route);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(chosb);
        panel.add(choss);
        //panel.add(text)
        panel.add(fer);
        panel.add(ferr);
        panel.add(ifer);
        panel.add(iferr);
        panel.add(iferrr);
        panel.add(addb);
        panel.add(amys);
        panel.add(adbf);
        panel.add(back);
        panel.add(addf);

        adbf.setVisible(false);
        amys.setVisible(false);
        addb.setVisible(false);
        freig.setVisible(false);
        pass.setVisible(false);
        chost.setVisible(false);
        book.setVisible(false);
        del.setVisible(false);
        ship1.setVisible(false);
        ship2.setVisible(false);
        route.setVisible(true);
        back.setVisible(false);
        choss.setVisible(false);
        chosb.setVisible(false);
        fer.setVisible(false);
        ferr.setVisible(false);
        ifer.setVisible(false);
        iferr.setVisible(false);
        iferrr.setVisible(false);
        addf.setVisible(false);

        getContentPane().add(panel);

        setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {//This is known as an anonymous function
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
            //  System.out.println("" + text.getText());

            fer.setVisible(false);
            ferr.setVisible(false);
            choss.setVisible(false);
            button.setVisible(false);
            back.setVisible(true);
            route.setVisible(false);
            chost.setVisible(true);
            freig.setVisible(true);
            pass.setVisible(true);
            amys.setVisible(false);
            addf.setVisible(false);
            adbf.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
         pass.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {//This is known as an anonymous function
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
            //  System.out.println("" + text.getText());

            fer.setVisible(true);
            ferr.setVisible(true);
            choss.setVisible(true);
            button.setVisible(false);
            back.setVisible(true);
            route.setVisible(false);
            chost.setVisible(false);
            freig.setVisible(false);
            pass.setVisible(false);
            amys.setVisible(false);
            adbf.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        fer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {//This is known as an anonymous function
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
            //  System.out.println("" + text.getText());
            ifer.setVisible(true);
            iferr.setVisible(true);
            iferrr.setVisible(true);
            choss.setVisible(false);
            chosb.setVisible(true);
            fer.setVisible(false);
            ferr.setVisible(false);
            route.setVisible(false);
            chost.setVisible(false);
            freig.setVisible(false);
            pass.setVisible(false);
            addb.setVisible(true);
            amys.setVisible(false);
            adbf.setVisible(false);
            addf.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
        iferr.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {//This is known as an anonymous function
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
            //  System.out.println("" + text.getText());
            ifer.setVisible(true);
            iferr.setVisible(true);
            iferrr.setVisible(true);
            choss.setVisible(false);
            chosb.setVisible(false);
            fer.setVisible(false);
            ferr.setVisible(false);
            route.setVisible(false);
            iferr.setFocusPainted(true);
            ship1.setVisible(true);
            book.setVisible(true);
            chost.setVisible(false);
            freig.setVisible(false);
            pass.setVisible(false);
            addb.setVisible(true);
            ship2.setVisible(false);
            amys.setVisible(false);
            adbf.setVisible(false);
            addf.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
            ifer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {//This is known as an anonymous function
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
            //  System.out.println("" + text.getText());
            ifer.setVisible(true);
            iferr.setVisible(true);
            iferrr.setVisible(true);
            choss.setVisible(false);
            chosb.setVisible(false);
            fer.setVisible(false);
            ferr.setVisible(false);
            route.setVisible(false);
            ifer.setFocusPainted(true);
            ship1.setVisible(false);
            ship2.setVisible(true);
            book.setVisible(true);
            chost.setVisible(false);
            freig.setVisible(false);
            pass.setVisible(false);
            addb.setVisible(true);
            adbf.setVisible(false);
            amys.setVisible(false);
            addf.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {//This is known as an anonymous function
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
            //  System.out.println("" + text.getText());
            fer.setVisible(false);
            ferr.setVisible(false);
            button.setVisible(true);
            choss.setVisible(false);
            back.setVisible(false);
            chosb.setVisible(false);
            ifer.setVisible(false);
            iferr.setVisible(false);
            iferrr.setVisible(false);
            route.setVisible(true);
            ship1.setVisible(false);
            ship2.setVisible(false);
            book.setVisible(false);
            chost.setVisible(false);
            freig.setVisible(false);
            pass.setVisible(false);
            addb.setVisible(false);
            del.setVisible(false);
            addf.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
        addf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {//This is known as an anonymous function
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
            //  System.out.println("" + text.getText());
            fer.setVisible(false);
            ferr.setVisible(false);
            button.setVisible(true);
            choss.setVisible(false);
            back.setVisible(false);
            chosb.setVisible(false);
            ifer.setVisible(false);
            iferr.setVisible(false);
            iferrr.setVisible(false);
            route.setVisible(true);
            ship1.setVisible(false);
            ship2.setVisible(false);
            book.setVisible(false);
            chost.setVisible(false);
            freig.setVisible(false);
            pass.setVisible(false);
            addb.setVisible(false);
            del.setVisible(false);
            adbf.setVisible(true);
            amys.setVisible(true);
            amys.setText(labelPrefixs + ++numAmy);
            addf.setVisible(false);
            adbf.setText(labelPrefixww + numClicks);
            }
        });

        book.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {//This is known as an anonymous function
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                addf.setVisible(true);
            addb.setVisible(true);
            addb.setText(labelPrefix + ++numClicks);
            del.setVisible(true);
        }
        });

            del.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {//This is known as an anonymous function
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
            addf.setVisible(true);
            addb.setText(labelPrefix + --numClicks);
            del.setVisible(true);
            del.setVisible(numClicks > 0);
            addf.setVisible(numClicks > 0);
        }
        });
}
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Boat("SwingApplication");






    }
}
```

**My Qestions Are:**

**Q1** Question one is in the title.

**Q2** When a user adds a fleet of 10 boats i need "Number of boats added" to reset to 0. while keep adding Boats used.

**Q3** When a user creates a fleet, the fleet could be of 5 amy boats and 10 frank.. how to make this visible insted of "Boats used"

**Q4** If the answer to the question 1 is yes i am on the right track. Is there any way of making the code a bit smaller? because im still adding stuff to it and it only gets bigger and more confusing.

**Q5** I'v looked at few Stack Overflow Forums to see how to make a line break in Jlabel. they said you cant do that but you can add HTML to it and make a (br). is there a way of not using HTML to make a line break? my friend did it i tried coping his code and it did not work for me.

***Thank guys! Any help is appreciated.***

**P.S** Please comment on any of your experiences about this article.

Comment: When you create a Swing GUI, you divide the application into model classes, view classes, and controller classes.  Boat, PassengerBoat, and FreightBoat are **model classes**.  These classes should contain **no** Swing components.  They hold fields and objects **only**.  Once you've created the model classes, then you can create the view classes.  Finally, you create the controller classes.

Answer (score 1):

For me you are create it in wrong way. 
Try to make your apps in 3 ways (you can use it like template):
 1. Action listener in your main class:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Demo1 implements ActionListener 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("b1");

    }

    protected void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(800,600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton b1 = new JButton("B1");
        f.add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                Demo1 app = new Demo1();
                app.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2. With anon class as Actionlistener
   http://pastebin.com/CNzi1ig9
3. Or in other class 
   http://pastebin.com/379dbPiZ

Comment: Thanks for the template! if i would create it like your template would it get rid of the questions i have?

Comment: @IAmADoughnut Yep. Btw. i think you use eclipse java? Maybe try NetBeans.. it has diffrent way for programming for me much easier.
Template 3rd is for big projects and for purity, i use often 2nd temp.

Comment: i heared my lecturer talking about eclipse but i think its going to be only in future, right now just Jcreator. but ill check out NetBeans anyway Thanks for the tips